# Problem with authorization through connexion

Tags: flask, swagger-ui, openapi, connexion

I am trying to login using swagger-ui and connexion.

To do this, I go through the login, get a token. I substitute this token in the header. I'm authorizing (it seems like it was successful as say `swagger-ui`), but when I try to make a request, I get an error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'.`

Looking at the source code - this method is here - https://github.com/zalando/connexion/blob/master/connexion/security/security_handler_factory.py#L339

Apparently, this is due to the fact that `auth_funcs = []`

Although there is a title in the request itself. If you test through `postman`, everything is fine too.

**openapi.yml**

```
paths:
  /articles/catalog/article/<article_id>/note/add:
    post:
      security:
        - bearerAuth: []


components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

Comment: Cool for the source code, but you should add your code otherwise how can the error be found ?

Comment: @FedericoBaù updated